# Coordinates of an object - Matlab

Tags: matlab

How can I find the top, button, left, right x,y coordinates of this object?

Code:

```
clc;
clear all;
 
Image = rgb2gray(imread('https://upload-icon.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/icons/png/1606078271536061993-512.png'));
 
BW = imbinarize(Image);
BW = imfill(BW,'holes');
BW = bwareaopen(BW, 100);
BW = padarray(BW,60,60,'both')
BW = imcomplement(BW);

imshow(BW)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The red pixels on the coordinate plot indicate the furthest most pixels to the left, right, top and bottom of the icon/image. This method similarly uses `for-loops` and `break()` statements to scan the image until a pixel of logical value "1" is found.

The scanning patterns include:

• Top → Scan image from top to bottom

• Bottom → Scan image from bottom to top

• Left → Scan image from left to right

• Right → Scan image from right to left

[image: Coordinate Plot]

```
clc;
clear all;
 
Image = rgb2gray(imread('https://upload-icon.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/uploads/icons/png/1606078271536061993-512.png'));

BW = imbinarize(Image);
BW = imfill(BW,'holes');
BW = bwareaopen(BW, 100);
BW = padarray(BW,60,60,'both');
BW = imcomplement(BW);

[Image_Height,Image_Width] = size(BW);

%Top (scanning from top to bottom)%
for Row_Scanner = 1: +1: Image_Height
    for Column_Scanner = 1: +1: Image_Width

    Pixel_Value =  BW(Row_Scanner,Column_Scanner);
    if(Pixel_Value == 1)
    Top = [Row_Scanner Column_Scanner];   
    break;
    end
    
        
    end
end

%Bottom (scanning from bottom to top)%
for Row_Scanner = Image_Height: -1: 1
    for Column_Scanner = 1: +1: Image_Width
    
    Pixel_Value =  BW(Row_Scanner,Column_Scanner);
    if(Pixel_Value == 1)
    Bottom = [Row_Scanner Column_Scanner]; 
    break;
    end
    
    end
end

%Left (scanning from left to right)%
for Column_Scanner = 1: +1: Image_Width
   for Row_Scanner = 1: +1: Image_Height
    
    Pixel_Value =  BW(Row_Scanner,Column_Scanner);
    if(Pixel_Value == 1)
    Left = [Row_Scanner Column_Scanner]; 
    break;
    end
    
   end
end

%Right (scanning from right to left)%
for Column_Scanner = Image_Width: -1: 1
   for Row_Scanner = 1: +1: Image_Height
    
    Pixel_Value =  BW(Row_Scanner,Column_Scanner);
    if(Pixel_Value == 1)
    Right = [Row_Scanner Column_Scanner];   
    break;
    end
     
   end
end

Coordinates_Image = zeros(Image_Height,Image_Width,3); 
Coordinates_Image(Top(1,1),Top(1,2),1) = 255;
Coordinates_Image(Bottom(1,1),Bottom(1,2),1) = 255;
Coordinates_Image(Left(1,1),Left(1,2),1) = 255;
Coordinates_Image(Right(1,1),Right(1,2),1) = 255;


Top_X = Top(1,2);
Top_Y = Top(1,1);

Bottom_X = Bottom(1,2);
Bottom_Y = Bottom(1,1);

Left_X = Left(1,2);
Left_Y = Left(1,1);

Right_X = Right(1,2);
Right_Y = Right(1,1);

fprintf("Top coordinate is (x,y) -> (%d,%d)\n",Top_X,Top_Y);
fprintf("Bottom coordinate is (x,y) -> (%d,%d)\n",Bottom_X,Bottom_Y);
fprintf("Left coordinate is (x,y) -> (%d,%d)\n",Left_X,Left_Y);
fprintf("Right coordinate is (x,y) -> (%d,%d)\n",Right_X,Right_Y);

subplot(1,2,1); imshow(BW);
title('Image');
subplot(1,2,2); imshow(Coordinates_Image);
title('Coordinate Plot');
xlabel('X-Axis'); ylabel('Y-Axis');
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using a loop. Find the first/last rows and columns whose sum is non-zero and break the loop once the condition is met.

```
BW = imcomplement(BW);

[r,c] = size(BW);

% Top cordinate: Find first row with non-zero sum
for i=1:r
    top = i;
    if sum(BW(i,:))~= 0
        break
    end
end

% Bottom cordinate: Find last row with non zero sum
for i=r:-1:1
    bottom = i;
    if sum(BW(i,:))~= 0
        break
    end
end

% Left cordinate: Find first column with non zero sum
for i=1:c
    left = i;
    if sum(BW(:,i))~= 0
        break
    end
end

% Right cordinate: find last column with non-zero sum
for i=c:-1:1
    right = i;
    if sum(BW(:,i))~= 0
        break
    end
end
```

Comment: Thanks but I am looking for the x,y coordinates

Comment: No Problem. You can use find() function of matlab to find the non-zero element index in each row and column you got earlier.